# PHP: Correct order of interface and class inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I have an abstract parent class P, and two concrete child classes C1 and C2.  C1 and C2 extend from P.

In parallel to this, I have three interfaces, iP, iC1 and iC2.  iC1 and iC2 extend from iP.

Obviously each child class should implement it's respective interface, but should the abstract parent class also implement its interface too?

Given that I will only be instantiating concrete classes, and these classes are bound to iP (by virtue of the interface inheritance hierarchy), I'm not sure if I really need P to implement iP?

Another alternative would be that I scrap the inheritance hierarchy on the interface side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sprit of interfaces is allowing decoupling, in other words, to separate the "what" from the "how".  It's not a really good practice to hava and interface per class as you are stating in your question since it has no sense.

You can have in iP the signature of all the methods that your classes are going to implement, and abstract class P that partially implements the common methods that are to be reused in your child classes and the signature of the methods that you plan to write later in your child classes.

In this way, its enough that C1 and C2 extends your abstract class P since you are forced to implement all the methods declared in your interface and in your abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without knowing the business model. 
But if you have an abstract class, my best guess is that you don't need interfaces for C1 and C2, just have one interface which P implements and also declares it's abstract method. Then the child classes extends P.